# Android spinner refresh without using an OnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, spinner, sharedpreferences

I have an issue I have been unable to figure out.  I have a spinner loaded from an ArrayList saved in SharedPreferences.  I allow the users to modify the spinner names through a PreferenceActivity in a separate class that is startActivityForResult.  It works but I cannot for the life of me make the spinner refresh itself with the new name(s) unless the app is closed and then reopened.

When the user uses the back key to close the Edit names window the result code and result_ok information is passed back correctly.  This is where I can't figure things out.  I know I need to use NotifyDataSetChanged but I can't figure out how to do it since the modifications are made in a separate class and not in the OnItemSelectedListener like so many answers to questions here on StackOverflow suggest for refreshing spinner data.

Here is my spinner code:

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        /* enable hardware acceleration on Android >= 3.0 */
        final int FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED = WindowManager.LayoutParams.class
                .getDeclaredField("FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED").getInt(null);
        getWindow().setFlags(FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
                FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    checkPreferences();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    this.findViewById(R.id.label_mode).setOnClickListener(this);
    this.findViewById(R.id.label_clear).setOnClickListener(this);
    this.findViewById(R.id.label_data).setOnClickListener(this);
    this.findViewById(R.id.label_wifi).setOnClickListener(this);
    this.findViewById(R.id.label_roam).setOnClickListener(this);
    this.findViewById(R.id.label_vpn).setOnClickListener(this);
    this.findViewById(R.id.label_invert).setOnClickListener(this);

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    // create the spinner
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    // profile names for spinner
    final List<String> profilestring = new ArrayList<String>();
    profilestring.add(prefs.getString("default",
            getString(R.string.defaultprofile)));
    profilestring.add(prefs.getString("profile1",
            getString(R.string.profile1)));
    profilestring.add(prefs.getString("profile2",
            getString(R.string.profile2)));
    profilestring.add(prefs.getString("profile3",
            getString(R.string.profile3)));
    profilestring.add(prefs.getString("profile4",
            getString(R.string.profile4)));
    profilestring.add(prefs.getString("profile5",
            getString(R.string.profile5)));
    profileposition = profilestring
            .toArray(new String[profilestring.size()]);

    // adapter for spinner
    adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, profileposition);

    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
    spinner.setSelection(prefs.getInt("itemPosition", 0));
    spinner.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int position, long id) {
                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    int index = parent.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    if (index == 0) {
                        editor.putInt("itemPosition", index);
                        editor.commit();
                        LoadDefaultProfile();
                    }
                    if (index == 1) {
                        editor.putInt("itemPosition", index);
                        editor.commit();
                        LoadProfile1();
                    }
                    if (index == 2) {
                        editor.putInt("itemPosition", index);
                        editor.commit();
                        LoadProfile2();
                    }
                    if (index == 3) {
                        editor.putInt("itemPosition", index);
                        editor.commit();
                        LoadProfile3();
                    }
                    if (index == 4) {
                        editor.putInt("itemPosition", index);
                        editor.commit();
                        LoadProfile4();
                    }
                    if (index == 5) {
                        editor.putInt("itemPosition", index);
                        editor.commit();
                        LoadProfile5();
                    }
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I then set my selection and run the spinner with spinner.post(New Runnable).

My preference screen is very simple.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="default"
    android:summary="Edit name for Default Profile"
    android:title="@string/defaultprofile" />

<EditTextPreference
    android:key="profile1"
    android:summary="Edit name for profile1"
    android:title="@string/profile1" />

<EditTextPreference
    android:key="profile2"
    android:summary="Edit name for profile2"
    android:title="@string/profile2" />

<EditTextPreference
    android:key="profile3"
    android:summary="Edit name for profile3"
    android:title="@string/profile3" />

<EditTextPreference
    android:key="profile4"
    android:summary="Edit name for profile4"
    android:title="@string/profile4" />

<EditTextPreference
    android:key="profile5"
    android:summary="Edit name for profile5"
    android:title="@string/profile5" />
```

EditNames class

```
public class EditProfileNames extends PreferenceActivity implements
    OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.prefs);
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(EditProfileNames.this,
            R.layout.prefs, false);

    for (int i = 0; i < getPreferenceScreen().getPreferenceCount(); i++) {
        initSummary(getPreferenceScreen().getPreference(i));
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Set up a listener whenever a key changes
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Unregister the listener whenever a key changes
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {
    updatePrefSummary(findPreference(key));
}

private void initSummary(Preference p) {
    if (p instanceof PreferenceCategory) {
        PreferenceCategory pCat = (PreferenceCategory) p;
        for (int i = 0; i < pCat.getPreferenceCount(); i++) {
            initSummary(pCat.getPreference(i));
        }
    } else {
        updatePrefSummary(p);
    }

}

private void updatePrefSummary(Preference p) {
    if (p instanceof ListPreference) {
        ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) p;
        p.setSummary(listPref.getEntry());
    }
    if (p instanceof EditTextPreference) {
        EditTextPreference editTextPref = (EditTextPreference) p;
        p.setSummary(editTextPref.getText());
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        resultOk();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

/**
 * Set the activity result to RESULT_OK and terminate this activity.
 */
private void resultOk() {
    final Intent response = new Intent(Api.PREF_PROFILES);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, response);
    finish();
}
```

}

So what do I have to do to refresh the spinner?  I know I could do it if the change was made in the OnItemSelectedListener but since it is an entirely different class that makes the changes I'm lost at the moment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are passing a reference to your array, `profileposition`, to another class so that it can add elements to it. You will also need to pass a reference to `adapter` to that class as well, so that it can call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after it has updated your array.

EDIT: Now that I see that you an Acitivty that you have started for a result is doing the updating of the array, you could just call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in your `onActivityResult()` callback.

Comment: That's what I've been trying to do but unlike my Listview where I can do something like this:  BaseAdapter adapter = (BaseAdapter) spinner.getAdapter(); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged;

The way to get the spinner to do the same alludes me.  :(

Comment: You could just make `adapter` a class variable. Then just do a null check on it before calling notifyDataSetChanged(). Not the cleanest solution, but it will get the job done, and it just is accessed on one thread so I see no implications with making it scoped to the class.

Comment: I set the adapter as a class variable and simply called adapter.notifyDataSetchanged from onActivityResult.  It didn't refresh the spinner.

Comment: Could you verify for me that the data in the underlying list was changed before notiftyDataSetChanged is called(and that it is actually called). Logging the information in the onActivityResult callback would probably be best.

Comment: Confirmed.  Logs catch the updated information in onActivityResult.  The names are definitely being changed.

Comment: Done.  All minor changes.  I have another adapter (non global) for a ListView which is why I made the global adapter1.  easier for keeping track.

Comment: Could you post the entire activity of the Spinner, I am slightly confused where this initialization is taking place.

Comment: Done.  The spinner initialization is in my onCreate.

Comment: You created adapter1 as the class adapter, but you are still setting adapter as the Adapter of your spinner.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the contents , call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter and that will solve the issue.

Try this way

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: What your suggesting is that I call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() from my PreferenceActivity class.  How would I call the adapter from an entirely different class?

Comment: Nopes, you need to call from your Spinner class

Comment: I've tried that.  That's why I'm confused.  When I get my RESULT_OK information I have a method that is called in order to refresh the spinner.  However, code like the following (I've tried many variations) doesn't work for me in regards to the spinner.

    BaseAdapter adapter = (BaseAdapter) spinner.getAdapter();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged;

Comment: Full code for the spinner and the PreferenceActivity has been posted in main post.  If you need more I can provide.

Comment: where is onActivityResult() code, on this method need to use notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Right now it simply calls another method called updateSpinner().  I have no code in updateSpinner right now because everything I've tried has failed.  I know that updateSpinner is being called though because of logs and simple toast messages.

Comment: adapter is not a global variable.  How would I declare it as a global to properly be used in the spinner?

Comment: Declare it above onCreate in your Activity

Comment: I made the ArrayAdapter a global variable and updated my code to coincide with it.  However, adapter.notifyDataSetChanged in my updateSpinner() method did not refresh the spinner.